# Where do I put helper methods for ActionMailer views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, helpermethods

I have a method that takes an array of strings and joins them so they do something like this:

```
>> my_arr
=> ["A", "B", "C"]
>> and_join(my_arr)
=> "A, B, and C"
```

Which I'd like my mailer to have access to so I can output some information into an email. I can't seem to find a good place to put it and putting it in the application_helper.rb file and it doesn't find it there. Where should it go?

Comment: Worth looking at the `to_sentence` extension method for arrays that rails provides.

Comment: @Shadwell, post that as an answer and I'll +1 it. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: similar one - http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/highlight-changes-being-made-on-activerecord-object-inside-mail/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use the [`helper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper) method in your mailer to define the helper class to use

```
# mailer_helper.rb
module MailerHelper
  def and_join(arr)
    # whatever …
  end
end

# my_mailer.rb
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper MailerHelper
  …
end
```

then you can use the methods in views as well.

Comment: Great. Add `include MailerHelper` to `MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base` as well to use the helper methods in `My Mailer` (like a subject formatter) in addition to any downstream views

Answer (score 10):

It would be worth looking at the `to_sentence` extension method for arrays that rails provides.

Answer (score 5):

An already answered question, but I didn't get where/what-file to modify from the other SO responses.  Here is how I did it:

At the bottom of app/config/initializers/devise.rb you can add this:

```
Devise::Mailer.class_eval do
  helper :application # includes "ApplicationHelper"
end
```

This example will include the methods in /app/helpers/application_helper.rb.  You could include another helper-file instead - if, for example, the method is only for the mailer or used for one other controller only.  The def I needed is used all over, so I put in in that file so all views could access it.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, for Rails 5.1, I had to use both include and helper methods, like this:

```
include ApplicationHelper
helper :application
```

And then just proceed to use the method normally.

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
  helper :application

  def my_mailer_method
    my_helper_method_declared_in_application_helper
    ..
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have some one off methods you want to use in the view, you can use `helper_method` directly in your mailer.

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def mailer
    mail to: '', subject: ''
  end

  private

  helper_method def something_to_use_in_the_view
  end
end
```

`something_to_use_in_the_view` will be available in your view.

Answer (score 4):

+1, worked fine, just a little correction:

You have to use **module** instead of **class** in the helper file:

```
# mailer_helper.rb
module MailerHelper
  def and_join(arr)
    # whatever …
  end
end
```