# Access helpers from mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have trying to access helper methods from a rails 3 mailer in order to access the current user for the session.

I put the helper :application in my mailer class, which seems to work, except the methods defined therein are not available to my mailer (i get undefined errors). Does anyone know how this is supposed to work?

Here's my class:

```
class CommentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "Andre Fournier <andre@gfournier.com>"

  helper :application
end
```

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Can you also include your code and method definition for getting the current user?

Comment: Sure, here it is (the reference in the mailer):
`:from => "#{current_sender.name} <#{current_sender.email}>"`
and the definition:
`def current_sender
   current_user
end`

Comment: I mean, do you have current_user defined in a helper method or in your application controller and if so, what's the definition?

Comment: In this app current_user is a helper method provided by Devise. However, when I call current_sender, which I defined in my application_helper file, I get an undefined error. The issue is not with current_user because it is never called.

Comment: My suggestion would be to add an alias to current_user from current_sender in your CommentMailer class instead of including the entire helper. If that doesn't work you'll need to make current_user available to your CommentMailer class. It's better to do this since it doesn't require including an entire helper module.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to find some way of making current_user available to the CommentMailer class, but so far, that is precisely what i've been uable to figure out.

Comment: Why not assigning current_user to an instance variable in your mailer method(s)? `@current_sender = current_user`? Then use the variable within your views.

Comment: similar one - http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/highlight-changes-being-made-on-activerecord-object-inside-mail/

Answer (score 72):

To enable you to access application helpers from the ActionMailer views, try adding this:

```
add_template_helper(ApplicationHelper)
```

To your ActionMailer (just under your `default :from` line).

Comment: Works! @Sean O'Hara - Y U don't accept this answer?

Comment: I had to include ::ApplicationHelper before add_template_helper(ApplicationHelper).

Comment: For rails 4+ you can also do `helper ApplicationHelper `

Answer (score 65):

#### Use `helper ApplicationHelper`

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: "Community Point <Team@CommunityPoint.ca>"
  helper ApplicationHelper
  helper NotificationMailerHelper

  # ...other code...
```

NOTE: These helper methods are **only available to the Views**. They are not available in the mailer class (`NotificationMailer` in my example).

If you need them in the actual mailer class, use `include ApplicationHelper`, like so:

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  include ApplicationHelper

  # ... the rest of your mailer class.

end
```

From [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681607/where-do-i-put-helper-methods-for-actionmailer-views).

Comment: It's important to know that these helper methods are not available in the mailer class (`NotificationMailer` in my example), but only to the views themselves. If you need them in the mailer class itself, you should be able to use `include ApplicationHelper` instead.

Answer (score 26):

This is a very old question, but I don't see the full answer, so I will try as I didn't find another resource.

It depends on what you are doing with the methods that have been defined in the helper module. If they are class methods, and everything that's not called on a specific instance seem to be a class methods for 3.2.13, you need to use

```
extend ApplicationHelper
```

if an instance methods

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

and if you want to use them in a mailer view

```
helper ApplicationHelper
```

Comment: Thank you for this !!! I have no way of marking this as an answer. - Are the extend / include / helper depreciable , ie using extend covers include and helper ?

Answer (score 7):

You could try mixing in the required helper module:

```
class CommentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work from the views. I'm guessing no. But it will definitely work if you want to use the helpers in the mailer class itself.

Answer (score 4):

Josh Pinter's answer is correct, but I discovered that it is not necessary.

What ***is*** necessary is to name the helper correctly.

`NotificationMailerHelper` is correct. `NotificationMailersHelper` (note the s) is not correct.

The class and filename of the helper must match and be correctly spelled.

Rails 3.2.2

Answer (score 3):

`include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` worked for me in the Mailer controller (.rb file). This allowed me to use the pluralize helper in a Mailer controller action (helpers worked fine from the get go in Mailer views). None of the other answers worked, at least not on Rails 4.2

Comment: Worked for me in Rails 5.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call helper method from ActionMailer you need to include helper (module) in Mailer file as, if Helper module name is “UserHelper”, then need to write following in Mailer file

```
class CommentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default :from => "Andre Fournier <andre@gfournier.com>"
    add_template_helper(UserHelper)
end
```

Or

```
class CommentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default :from => "Andre Fournier <andre@gfournier.com>"
    include UserHelper
end
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The single method version of promoting a method to being a helper that is available in ApplicationController also works in ActionMailer:

```rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper_method :marketing_host

  def marketing_host
    "marketing.yoursite.com"
  end
end
```

from there you can call `marketing_host` from any of your mailer views

Comment: This is the simplest way in Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are doing here, but when I want to access current_user from a mailer, I make a mailer method that I pass the user to as an argument:

```
class CommentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "Andre Fournier <andre@gfournier.com>"

  def blog_comment(user)
    @recipients                   = user.email
    @from                         = "andre@gfournier.com"
    @sent_on                      = Time.now
    @timestamp                    = Time.now
    @user                         = user
  end
end
```

With the above, @user, as well as all the other instance variables, are accessible from inside the mailer views ./views/comment_mailer/blog_comment.html.erb and ./views/comment_mailer/blog_comment.text.erb

Separately, you can make a helper called

comment_mailer_helper.rb

and put into that helper any methods that you want to be available to your mailer's views. This seems to me more like what you might want, regarding helpers, because helpers are designed to help views, whereas a mailer is analogous to a controller.

Answer (score 0):

None of the `*_path` helpers are accessible by default inside of an email. It is necessary instead to use the `*_url` form of the wanted helper. So, for instance, instead of using `user_path(@user)` it is necessary to use `user_url(@user)`.
See at [Action Mailer basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views).

Answer (score -4):

A hackish means of achieving what I wanted is to store the objects I need (current_user.name + current_user.email) in thread attributes, like so: `Thread.current[:name] = current_user.name`. Then in my mailer I just assigned new instance variables to those values stored in the thread: `@name = Thread.current[:name]`. This works, but it won't work if using something like delayed job.