# Using number_with_precision on application_controller in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I did add `require 'action_view'` & `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`  ⬇

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  require 'action_view'
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

And, when I call it in my => `def self.form_price formatted_price, total, total_till`

```
puts number_with_precision(total, :precision => 2, :delimiter => ',')
```

Get this message:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `eval': undefined method `number_with_precision' for ApplicationController:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Why are you putting this in your controller? It should be in the view, or better yet a decorator.

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't be in the controller, but :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.number_with_precision(total, :precision => 2, :delimiter => ',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this:

```
view_context.number_with_precision(total, :precision => 2, :delimiter => ',')
```

Please refer [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130150/rails-how-to-use-a-helper-inside-a-controller)

Comment: Thank you & sorry for long response. I tried it & getting this msg:
undefined local variable or method `view_context' for ApplicationController:Class (NameError)

Comment: i have tried with rails 3.2.14 for me it is working.

Comment: I have 3.2.13 :) Anyway, thank you for your comment & help. +1 :)