# Creating current variables in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I am a rookie in Rails. I am using Rails 4 and I could not find how they do this or what it is called.

I got this idea from `devise` where you can use `devise` and implement such thing in your `application.html.erb` file:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
      Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong>.
```

Where `user` is the devise model.
However when I try to search for `user_signed_in` or `current_user` variable, I cannot find it at all!

So essentially what I want to do is link this `user` model (which is used for `devise`) with another model that I created called `profile`. These models are linked by their ids, and if user has not created a profile, then simply ask user to create his/her profile.
To do that, I've written this to `application.html.erb`:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && (current_profile.id != current_user.id)? %>
    <%= link_to 'You have not created your profile! Please create your profile first.', update_profile_index_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
<% else %>
    <%= yield %>
<% end %>
```

Which does not work as expected because I have not defined `current_profile`. The error that I am getting is:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_profile' for #<#<Class:0x000000044d6c60>:0x00000005d64110>
```

My question is, how do I create a variable named `current_profile` that would contain the current profile, like `current_user` that devise does?

Comment: Why don't you simply use current_user.profile ?

Comment: current_user is a devise model. It does not have a profile?

Comment: if you define has_one profile on the user model, then current_user.profile will work

Comment: I already did that for both and it doesn't work. I am getting undefined method `profile?' for #<User:0x00000002f82c88>
 error if I do that

Comment: then you need to define `def profile?; return self.profile; end` on your User model

Comment: or call it without the question mark. And you need user_id:integer to be defined on the profile model for the association to work

Comment: for defining that, when I used that then I get a SQL error:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: profiles.user_id: SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1

Which is expected because, user_id in profiles is not set yet (that's why it should be created)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60088/discussion-between-rafal-and-sarp-kaya).

Answer (score 3):

The usual setup for this is to add a Profile model with a user_id:integer field.

Define an assocition on the User model

```
has_one :profile
```

Then you can access it directly using

```
current_user.profile
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
class User
  has_one :profile
  # ...

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
  # ...

module ApplicationHelper # app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  def current_profile
    @current_profile ||= current_user.try(:profile)
    @current_profile
  end
  # ...

# view
<% if user_signed_in? && current_profile.blank? %>
  <%= link_to 'You have not created your profile! Please create your profile first.', update_profile_index_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
<% else %>
  <%= yield %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have has_one in Profile as well because I want to strict that one profile has only one user?

Comment: @SarpKaya see [Choosing Between `belongs_to` and `has_one`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one)

Comment: It worked like a charm! And this kind of thing was what I was wanting at the first place!

Comment: @Stefan I want to use primary key of both, I don't really need a separate field, therefore both of them are has_one.

Comment: @SarpKaya where do you store the foreign key - is there a `profile_id` field in your `users` table or a `user_id` field in your `profiles` table?

Comment: I don't have any extra field in `users` table. I have `user_id` field in `profiles` table. I don't have any extra id field for the `profiles` table. So I simply want to create one-on-one id matching. Ie, I have 10 users, `user.id(10)` is a quick user and creates a profile before them, in that case the `user_id` field in the `profiles` would be 10. By doing that I simply save one entire id field in `profiles` and in `users` table.

Comment: The model holding the `belongs_to :something` part is the model that holds the column `something_id`. In your case `User has_one :profile` and `Profile belongs_to :user`

Comment: For some reason this does not work in controllers. It works in views but when I am at the controller it simply cannot find. However the `current_user` is available in both controller and viewer. When I look at the content of self, I cannot find current_profile?

Comment: See this answer @SarpKaya http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130150/rails-how-to-use-a-helper-inside-a-controller

Comment: @MrYoshiji that does not include anything for Rails 4

Comment: add `include ApplicationHelper` in `ApplicationController` to make the helper method `current_profile` available for all controllers