# How to access current_user in rails action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I have to access the current user into my action mailer, but I getting following error

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<WelcomeMailer:0xa9e6b230>
```

by using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937208/access-helpers-from-mailer) I am using application helper for getting the current user.
Here is my **WelcomeMailer**

```
class WelcomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'mail_layout'

  def send_welcome_email
    usr = find_current_logged_in_user
    Rails.logger.info("GET_CURRENT_USER_FROM_Helper-->#{usr}")
  end
end
```

and my **application helper** is as follows

```
def find_current_logged_in_user
    #@current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    # @current_user ||= session[:current_user_id] && User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])
    Rails.logger.info("current_user---> #{current_user}")
    current_user
  end
```

Also I tried with session and cookies. So how can I resolve this error or is there any other method for accessing current user in action mailer.
I am using `Rails 3.2.14 and ruby ruby 2.1.0`

Comment: Couldn't you pass current_user from controller? Like `send_welcome_email(current_user)`

Comment: I am sending email from the model.

Comment: This could help then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937208/access-helpers-from-mailer

Comment: I referred the same link and I can use `find_current_logged_in_user` helper method into the mailer but it is giving error for `current_user`

Comment: By the way, in your `find_current_logged_in_user`, you initialize `@current_user` and then use `current_user`. Is it misspelling?

Comment: Actually, I have commented the code for @current_user

Comment: If this is being called from a model then have the controller invoking the model pass the current user to the model, and have the model pass it on to the mailer

Comment: It could be argues that the model shouldn't really be sending emails. Thus a new object with that responsibility, injected with the appropriate model and user.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't try to access `current_user` from inside a Mailer.  Instead, pass the user into the mailer method. For example,

```
class WelcomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user)
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => 'Welcome')       
  end
end
```

To use it from within a contoller, where you have access to `current_user`:

```
WelcomeMailer.welcome_email(current_user).deliver
```

From within a model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :send_welcome_email

  def send_welcome_email
    WelcomeMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver
  end
end
```