# Rails 4: How to use ApplicationHelper methods in mailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, helper

I have a helper defined in my application_helper.rb that I would like to use in my mailer view, but just doing

```
<%= helper_method(param) %>
```

in the mailer_view.html.erb file gets me an 'undefined method' error.

Is there another way to do this? I would hate to have to put the same helper somewhere else.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access helpers from mailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937208/access-helpers-from-mailer)

Answer (score 10):

Apparently this has been asked before (who knew!) :). The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937208/access-helpers-from-mailer) is to include

```
helper ApplicationHelper
```

in the example_mailer.rb file:

```
class ExampleMailer < ApplicationMailer
  helper ApplicationHelper
  ...
end
```