# How to call an ApplicationHelper method in Mailer with Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper, ruby-on-rails-6, mailer

I have a helper function to generate email for user as below

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Generate unique email for user based on their first and only cat id
  def unique_email_for_user(user)
    "category#{user.cats.first.id}@mywebsite.com"
  end
end
```

I can call this **unique_email_for_user** function in my controllers, but not in my Mailer as below

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  # Call application_helpers      
  helper :application

  # match the name to views/mailer/send_reminder.html.erb
  def send_reminder(user)
    @user = user

    # Send email to user
    mail(to: @user.email, reply_to: unique_email_for_user(@user), subject: "My email subject")
  end
end
```

I get the error as below. I thought adding `helper :application` to my Mailer would make the necessary connections, No?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access helpers from mailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937208/access-helpers-from-mailer)

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

instead of

```
helper :application
```

Comment: where did you put the 'include'?