# Rails 4.1: access current_user in ActionMailer::Preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Rails 4.1 has a nice way to [preview mailers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Previewing+emails) with `ActionMailer::Preview`.  All of my mailers take a `user` parameter, and I would like  to pass in `current_user` (from Devise) for the preview.

If I try this, it doesn't work.

```rb
class SubscriptionsMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  # Preview this email at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/subscriptions_mailer/new
  def new
    SubscriptionsMailer.new(current_user)
  end
end
```

It returns `undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for #<SubscriptionsMailerPreview:0xa6d4ee4>`.

I suspect this is because `current_user` is defined by Devise in `ApplicationController`, and according to the docs, `ActionMailer` uses `AbstractController::Base`.  In that case, would storing `current_user` in a class variable be a bad idea?

Does anyone know how I can use the `current_user` helper in `ActionMailer::Preview`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would happen if you move your mailer job to the background? How would you get the current user then?

The mailer and its preview should not know about the `current_user`. The mailer's job is to send the mail to a user it receives. The preview is there to visually demonstrate its behaviour.

Create a new user in your mailer preview, and pass it to the mailer.

```
  def new
    user = User.create! # etc...
    SubscriptionsMailer.new(user)
  end
```

It doesn't matter who the user is. It matters that it's a user object.

If you want to test that the application will send a mail to the `current_user`, write a functional test for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are right method defined in Controller won't be available in helper.
These posts can help you: 
[Where do I put helper methods for ActionMailer views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681607/where-do-i-put-helper-methods-for-actionmailer-views)  
  [Access helpers from mailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937208/access-helpers-from-mailer)  
https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/168949